# Looking for regex to erase href text

Tags: regex

If I have a bunch of urls like this:

```
<li><a href="http://www.xyz.com/sometext/someothertext/123/sometext/">Xyz 123</a></li>  
<li><a href="http://www.xyz.com/345/sometext/someothertext/">Xyz 345</a></li>
```

What would a regex look like to erase the urls inside the hrefs so that they become:

```
<li><a href="">Xyz 123</a></li> 
<li><a href="">Xyz 345</a></li>
```

Comment: Which language/regex implementation are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you like:

```
/href=\"([^\"]*)\"/
```

Basically match `href="<any text but a '"'>"`.

Answer (score 2):

Search for `<a href="[^"]*"` and replace with `<a href=""`.

If you add more details about which language you're using, I can be more specific. Be aware also that regular expressions are usually not the tool of choice when dealing with HTML.

Comment: *regular expressions are usually not the tool of choice when dealing with HTML* True in general, but this subset (an href attribute) is regular so regex is fine for this particular case. (+1 anyway, but just wanted to make it clear)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **do not use regex to parse HTML** — why? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege).

Process the HTML using an XML reader / XML document processing engine. Then use XPath to find nodes matching your criteria and alter `href` attributes in the DOM.

Note: For HTML which is not well-formed XML a more-general HTML (SGML) parser is required.

Answer (score 0):

I partially agree with the others but a more complete version would be

```
/(<a[^>]+href\s*=\s*\")(.*?)("[^>]*>)/$1$3/gi
```